# Show that any finite field has exactly $2^n$ sets using atoms of the field expressed in terms of sets in the field

Tags: measure-theory

> Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$ be a measure space. A set $A$ in $\mathcal{F}$ is said to be an atom if there is no non-empty proper subset of $A$ which is in $\mathcal{F}$. If $\mathcal{F}$ is finite, describe its atoms in terms of interesection and complements of sets from $\mathcal{F}$. Use this to show that any finite field has exactly $2^n$ sets.

If $A$ is an atom in $\mathcal{F}$, then $\forall B\subset A$ (proper), we have either $B=\emptyset$ or $B\notin\mathcal{F}$. Now, for all $B_i\in\mathcal{F}$, we have
(i) $A\subseteq B_i$
(ii) $A\subseteq B_i^c$
(iii) $C=B_i\cap A\subset A$, which is an impossibility.
Therefore, $A=\cap_{i=1}^n C_i$ where $C_i=\begin{cases}B_i&\text{if, }A\subseteq B_i\\B_i^c&\text{if, }A\subseteq B_i\end{cases}$ where, $\mathcal{F}=n$.

Is this correct? How do I use this to show the last part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following holds for any field $\mathcal{F}$ (if it's not apparent to you, you should show it's true, using only simple manipulation of sets in a field):

> Let $\mathcal{A} \subset \mathcal{F}$ denote the subset of atoms of $\mathcal{F}$.
> For each $B \in \mathcal{F}$, we can define $\mathcal{A}_B = \{A \in \mathcal{A} : A \subseteq B\} \subseteq \mathcal{A},$ and for each finite $\mathcal{B} \subseteq \mathcal{A}$ we have $\bigcup \mathcal{B} \in \mathcal{F}$.
>
> Then, for any finite $\mathcal{B} \subseteq \mathcal{A}$, we have $\mathcal{B} = \mathcal{A}_{\bigcup \mathcal{B}}$ and for any $B \in \mathcal{F}$, we have $\bigcup \mathcal{A}_B \subseteq B$.

That's as far as we can go with general fields.  For finite fields, however, the restriction to finite subsets of $\mathcal{A}$ becomes trivial, and we can show that $\bigcup \mathcal{A}_B = B$, which will show that $|\mathcal{F}| = |\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{A})| = 2^{|\mathcal{A}|}$.

To do this, we may use what you've already shown, that "All atoms have the form $\bigcap_{i=1}^m C_i$" where $C_i$ is either $B_i$ or its complement, along with a fact that you may have missed that "All sets of the form $\bigcap_{i=1}^m C_i$ are either atoms or empty".

Specifically, suppose $B \in \mathcal{F}$ is given by $B=B_j$ for some $1 \leq j\leq m$.  Then the union of all the sets $\bigcap_{i=1}^m C_i$ such that $C_j = B_j$ is the union of atoms and empty sets and it equals $B_j$.

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean $2^n$ subsets? I would say: define $\mathcal{F} : = \mathcal{P} (X)$, then you have $A$ atom iff $A = \{a\}, a \in X$ of cardinality $n$.

With your previous analysis, instead of choosing $B_i$ or $B_i^c$, chose only the $B_i$ that verify $\{a\} \subseteq B_i$, from that, you define $f(B) \in \{0,1\}^{X}$ by $f(B)_a = 1$ iff $\{a \} \subseteq B_i$ for $a \in X$ and $B \in \mathcal{F}$.
Show that it is bijection (with your previous work) then you have $\sharp F = 2^{\sharp X} = 2^n$.

Comment: Your first paragraph is odd.  Just to check: Are you answering a question about [a field of sets](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_of_sets) or about [the algebraic structure using the same name](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_(mathematics))?

Comment: @BrianMoehring I get the misunderstanding (from the language barrier) I don't know why English chose the same names for the algebraic structure and the measurement theory structure. In French it is called a "Tribe" which means tribe.. I will edit my post thanks for the comment (I originally answered thinking he wanted to compute $\sharp \mathcal{P}(k)$ with $k$ a finite field of cardinality $n$ which seemed odd to me...)

Comment: Note that my concern was about the entire first paragraph (even the part still there).  I would interpret the underlying problem as showing that every finite field of sets (a finite tribe/clan in the French school) is order-isomorphic to $\mathcal{P}(X)$ for a finite set $X$, so assuming $\mathcal{F} := \mathcal{P}(X)$ at best leaves off the main part of the argument showing how we may simplify to that case.